# How do I filter on a text box and checkbox in Angular >= 15?

Tags: angular, filter

How do I go about creating a filter as mentioned in the subject line?

Here are some of the code snippets from what I've tried!

example-list.component.html

```
...
<app-input label="Search" [model]="this" propertyName="freeTextSearch" [readOnly]="false" [keyfilter]="alphaNumOnly" (keyup)="searchByFilter($event)"></app-input>
<app-checkbox label="Is Active" [model]="filter" (click)="resetSearchGrid()" propertyName="isActive"></app-checkbox>
...
```

example-list.component.ts

```
...
searchByFilter(event) {
  const listProps = new ListProps<ExampleFilter>();
  listProps.filter = this.filter;
  listProps.freeTextSearch = this.freeTextSearch;
  this.store.dispatch(this.actionCreator({ props: listProps }));
}

resetSearchGrid() {
  if (this.filter.isActive === false) {
    this.search(true);
  }
  else {
    this.search(true);
  }
}
...
```

list-filter-props.model.ts

```
...
export class ListProps<T> implements IListProps<T> {
    page: number;
    count: number;
    filter: T;
    sortBy: string[];
    freeTextSearch: string;
    constructor(page?: number, count?: number, filter?: T, sortBy?: string[], freeTextSearch?: string){
        page = page;
        count = count;
        filter = filter;
        sortBy = sortBy;
        freeTextSearch = freeTextSearch;
    }
}

export interface IListProps<T>{
    page: number;
    count: number;
    filter: T;
    sortBy: string[];
    freeTextSearch: string;
}

export interface IListOptionsProps{
    page: number;
    count: number;
}

export class ListOptionsProps implements IListOptionsProps{
    page: number;
    count = listOptionCount;
}
...
```

example-filter.model.ts

```
...
export interface IExampleFilter {
    code: string | null;
    description: string | null;
    isActive: boolean;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}

export class ExampleFilter implements IExampleFilter {
    code: string;
    description: string;
    isActive = true;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}
...
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

Thanks very much.